# Mocking for a Controller Unit-tests with ScalaTest + Play

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework, scalatest

I try to write a unit test for a small function in a controller using Play/ScalaTest+ Play. The function I want to test looks like this:

```
   def functionToTest(id: String) = Action.async {
    implicit request =>
      lang
      deeperFunction{ implicit context =>
        ...
      }
  }
```

The deeperFunction

```
  def deeperFunction(block: Context => Future[Result])(implicit request: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {

    // returns Future.successful(Found("DummyUrltoRedirect"))
}
```

}

The deeperFunction is inherited from a trait and I don't want use the real one here because it's a unit test and so I want to use a matcher instead

```
  val deeperMock = mock[Rainmaker]
  val contextMock = mock[Context]

  val controller = new Controller()(.....) // list of implicit arguments


  "Controller" must {

    "return something" in {

      val request = FakeRequest("GET", "/something")
      when(deeperMock.deeperFunction(anyObject)(anyObject)) thenReturn Future.successful(Found("DummyUrlToRedirect"))

   
      val id = "id"
      val result = controller.functionToTest(id).apply(request)

      status(result) mustBe Ok
    }
  }
```

But when I run this, the line "val result = controller.functionToTest(id).apply(request)" still seems to call the real deeperFunction, not the fake one and therefore throws a null matcher at some point.
I also tried to use

```
          when(controller.deeperFunction(anyObject)(anyObject)) thenReturn Future.successful(Found("DummyUrlToRedirect"))
```

instead, because the deeperFunction is inherited, but with the same result.
I tried to stick to theses instructions

[ScalaTest+Play](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaTestingWithScalaTest#Testing-your-application-with-ScalaTest)

[dzone](https://dzone.com/articles/beginners-guide-for-mocking-in-scala)

but it seems I am still missing some basics/understanding. Thanks in advance.

Comment: your question is clear but I think the code is not enough to figure out what is the problem. Please, the next time try to add a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
About the problem, in the test, are you adding the mock `deeperMock` to the `new Controller`?

Comment: Does the controller extends the trait containing `deeperFunction`?

Comment: Is the deeperFunction part of  Rainmaker in your controller?